# Java Regex required to append a string

Tags: java, regex, replace, append

`Java` Regex required to append a string for example
I have a text like `abc=qwerty&sessionid=1334356547&fee=500&abcd=345...`

I have to change the `string` as

```
abc=qwerty&sessionid=[SESSIONID]1334356547[/SESSIONID]&fee=[PRICE]500[/PRICE]&abcd=345...
```

Need this only for specific parameters like sessionidd fee etc..

Please help if this possible with Regex ?

Answer (score 0):

fee/PRICE left as exercise,

```
'abc=qwerty&sessionid=1334356547&fee=500&abcd=345...'.replace(/(sessionid=)([^&]*)/,'$1[SESSIONID]$2[/SESSIONID]')
```